# Font in the stackoverflow icon

Tags: support, design

Does anyone know the font in which "stack **overflow**" is written in the site's logo?

It's on the sprite [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/sprites.svg?v=46c88edf8d39)

(it seems to be two fonts btw, the bold and non-bold part, but I may be mistaken)

Comment: UberMeta dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21099/248731

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [FF Din Pro](https://www.fontshop.com/families/ff-din)

Comment: Well that was quick. I searched, but apparently not well enough. It says I can accept your answer in 11 minutes. Sit tight.

Comment: @GerbenRampaart the link I posted was literally the first Google hit for *"stack overflow logo font"* - what searching did you do?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I google the whole day but the ONE time I only use the SO search box because I figured it would have been asked before, I get burned. Well, if you must know, it hurts sir, it hurts.